# For-loop still increments after execution condition false

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm a novice with C so this question most likely has an easy solution but I can't see it. I noticed that my output is not what I am expecting and after several hours of debugging I realized that one of my for loops was not behaving as expected. Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
        {
            if ((temp_array[i]) == 0xCADE | (temp_array[i]) == 0xDADA)
            {

                printf("i is %d\n",i );
                i += 2;

                printf("i is now %d\n",i );

                n_body = temp_array[i];

                i++;

                printf("n_body is %d\n",n_body );

                for (count = 0, j = flag_index; count < n_body; i++, j++, count++)
                {

                    machine->memory[j] = temp_array[i];
                    printf("LETS SEE, i in loop is %d\n",i );
                    printf("LETS SEE, j in loop is %d\n",j );
                    printf("LETS SEE, count in loop is %d\n", count);

                }

                printf("\n");
                printf("LETS SEE, i out of loop is %d\n",i );
                printf("LETS SEE, j out of loop is %d\n",j );
                printf("LETS SEE, count out of loop is %d\n", count);

                machine->memory[j+1] = flag;

                //printf("flag is %d\n",flag );
                printf("machine memory index 18 is %d \n", machine->memory[18]);

            }

            // else
            // {
            //  continue;
            // }

            //printf("index is %d\n",i );
        }
```

The culprit is the second (nested) for-loop. I noticed that variables i, j, and count are incrementing once the execution condition `count < n_body`is not longer true. At this particular point, `n_body` is 18, `i` is 3, `bytes` is 64 and `flag_index` is 0. I've posted the output from the last few iterations of the for-loop and output from the print statements outside the for loop:

```
LETS SEE, i in loop is 18
LETS SEE, j in loop is 15
LETS SEE, count in loop is 15
LETS SEE, i in loop is 19
LETS SEE, j in loop is 16
LETS SEE, count in loop is 16
LETS SEE, i in loop is 20
LETS SEE, j in loop is 17
LETS SEE, count in loop is 17

LETS SEE, i out of loop is 21
LETS SEE, j out of loop is 18
LETS SEE, count out of loop is 18
```

Why are they incrementing? I thought that a for-loop shuts down(both execution of body and pre-post increments) once the execution condition is no longer true?

Comment: Are you sure you want a bitwise or `|` and not a logical or `||`?

Comment: For `count < 18` to fail, `count` must reach `18` ... not sure why you would expect it to end up on 17.

Comment: You increment `i` in both loops, e.g. `for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++)` ... `for (count = 0, j = flag_index; count < n_body; i++, ...)`

Comment: @Schwern, Thanks for the catch. I indeed wanted a logical OR, that was a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 3):

It updates whatever variables then tests the conditions. If the conditions are true it goes again. If false it exits. So if you have `for(x = 0; x < 5; ++x);` x's value will be 5 if you print it outside the loop (x has to be 5 for x < 5 to be false).

You can find flow diagrams of for loops online if you search. Here's one from geeksforgeeks:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is normal. You can see with a small demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        printf("i in loop: %d\n", i);
    }
    
    printf("i after loop: %d\n", i);
}

$ ./test
i in loop: 0
i in loop: 1
i in loop: 2
i after loop: 3
```

The relevant part of the standard is this:

> 6.8.5.3 The `for` statement
>
> 1 The statement
>
> `for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement`
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body. ***The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after each execution of the loop body.***

Every time the body executes, the increment happens. If the body runs three times, that's three iterations of `i++`.

You can also think of a for loop like this.

```
// for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
int i = 0;
while( i < 3 ) {
    printf("i in loop: %d\n", i);
    i++;
}
```

So your inner loop is equivalent to..

```
// for (count = 0, j = flag_index; count < n_body; i++, j++, count++) {
count = 0, j = flag_index;
while( count < n_body ) {                
    machine->memory[j] = temp_array[i];
    i++, j++, count++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The sample program clarified my error. It looks like  I will have to manually decrement the index variables outside the for-loop so that they have the values I need for the rest of the program. I wish there was a more streamlined way though...